# Monotonicity of a ratio of conditional expectation operator

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis

Let a pair of random variables $(X, Y)$ over a finite product space $\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}$ be given. The conditional expectation operator is defined as 
$$(T_Yf) (y):=\mathbb{E}[f(X)|Y=y],$$
where $f$ is a real-valued function acting on $\mathcal{X}$.

It is well known the the operator $T$ is contractive in $L^p$-norm for $p\geq 1$, i.e., 
$$||Tf||_p\leq ||f||_p,$$
which can be easily proved using convexity of the map $t\mapsto t^p$ and Jensen's inequality.

I am looking at the map $p\mapsto \frac{||Tf||_p}{||f||_p}$ for $p\geq 1$.
I am trying to see if this  map is monotonic or not. Any idea?

Comment: Does this monotonicity break for an arbitrary contractive operator?

Comment: @suvrit, I focus only on conditional expectation operator. For arbitrary contractive operator, I guess, the monotonicity breaks.

Comment: I asked, because it is not clear from the outset, where would the fact that $T$ is a conditional expectation operator play a role for monotonicity --- it seems to be used mostly for the contractivity. On the other hand, even non-contractive operators can lead to a monotonic ratio, so maybe your hypothesis does play a role...

Comment: By "over a finite product" you probably mean "with values in"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if $X=\{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{1,2,3\}$. Equip both $X$ and $Y$ with the uniform probability measure. Set $f(x,1)=1$, $f(x,2)=x$ and $f(x,3)=2$. 
Then $Tf(x,1)=1$; $Tf(x,2)=1.5$ and $Tf(x,3)=2$.

Notice that $\|f\|_1=\|Tf\|_1=1.5$ and $\|f\|_\infty=\|Tf\|_\infty=2$,
but $\|f\|_2>\|Tf\|_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
Now we know the map $p\mapsto \frac{||Tf||_p}{||f||_p}$ is not monotonic. How about the map  $p\mapsto \sup_{f\neq 0}\frac{||Tf||_p}{||f||_p}$?